# How to have plotmath symbols and line breaks in ggplot facet labels

Tags: r, ggplot2

I can have a plotmath symbol in a `ggplot2` facet, but that removes the line breaks. For example:

```
library(tidyverse)

mpg %>% 
  mutate(
    v1 = c("V1%->%V2",
           "V3%->%V4") %>% 
      rep(each = 117),
    v2 = c("A~~long~~label~~with\n~~a~~line~~break",
           "Another~~long~~label\n~~with~~a~~line~~break") %>%
      rep(each = 117)
    ) %>% 
  ggplot(
    aes(displ, cty)
  ) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_grid(v2 ~ v1, labeller = label_parsed)
```

returns this

[image]

which has the desired symbols in the column labels, but the line breaks are removed from the row facets.

How can I include the arrows in the column labels without removing the line breaks from the rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use the plotmath syntax, there are no such things as line breaks. Instead, you can use `atop()` For example

```
mpg %>% 
  mutate(
    v1 = c("V1%->%V2",
           "V3%->%V4") %>% 
      rep(each = 117),
    v2 = c("atop('A long label with','a line break')",
           "atop('Another long label','with a line break')") %>%
      rep(each = 117)
  ) %>% 
  ggplot(
    aes(displ, cty)
  ) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_grid(v2 ~ v1, labeller = label_parsed)
```

Comment: thanks! removed references to unicode so that this question might be more useful to others.